# Standing water in sump pit is stinking up the place

Tags: sump

I have a production facility with two connected INTERIOR storm drains and sump pits.  These drain to an external storm drain through a oil and sand separator.  The problem is we occasionally drain to these storm drains but not every day.  The water has gotten swampy smelling.  Is there any reason I cant fill the sump pit up to the drain pipe to minimize the amount of standing water and drain out most of the water at every use?

Comment: pour in some chlorine bleach

Comment: use pool salt that will kill the bacteria

Comment: bleach has not been effective.  I put in about a cup and it smells after 3 days.  Any reason why i cant fill it in?

Comment: Do you not have a pump?

Comment: No pump and putting one in would be prohibitively expensive.  This is an odd situation.  The pit gravity flows to another pit and then an external storm drain.  It was previously used to wash UPS trucks and these storm drains are where the waste would flow.  

What I want to do is fill them to the drain pipe so there is no standing water.  I am dondering why I need to have a sump pit in the first place as opposed to a large floor drain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a commercial installation, not [diy.se].

Answer (score 0):

The pit would have been designed to settle the solids so that outflow pipes don't plug up. Every so often you can drain the pit and remove the settled debris from the bottom. Thi design would allow only the liquids flow out of the pit to prevent blockages. When cleaning commercial vehicles on a regular, this pit would add some level of protection. However if you have a grate with only runoff liquids entering the pit then you may reduce the depth to eliminate standing water. Or better yet, add a p-trap to create a water barrier to eliminate downstream odors. This will prevent off games from returning into your dwelling.

Have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please give your answer a quick [edit] to correct the typos.

Comment: I know some folks who play "off games". I wouldn't let them in, either.